# AngularJS CORS error while making post request to the local nodeJS server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, cors

I'm trying to send json data over post request but getting errors, I've tried many answers of stackoverflow but not getting answer I've also tried `jsonp` method but not getting any thing.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/lvl/2/data. Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
>  No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> angular.js:14516 Possibly unhandled rejection:
>   {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost:3000/lvl/2/data","headers":{"Authorization":"Basic
>   dGVzdDp0ZXN0","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"data":{"Code":"test data"}},"statusText":""}

**http post request:**

```
$http({
    url:'http://localhost:3000/lvl/2/data',
    method:"POST",
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data: {
        'Code': 'test data'
    }
}).then(function() {
    console.log('submitted')
});
```

**NodeJs Post request:**

```
router.post('/lvl/2/data', function (req, res){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    res.header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('submitted');
});
```

Comment: does your nodejs handle `OPTIONS` preflight request correctly?

Comment: although `Origin 'null'` suggests the page that is making the request is loaded using `file://` protocol

Comment: your server isnt work like you doing

Comment: yes page is loaded using file:// protocol

Comment: I'm using http-server but still not working @JaromandaX

Comment: does your nodejs code handle `OPTIONS` preflight request correctly? What is the error now that you are using http for the page? (it **won't** be the same error)

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/lvl/2/data. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
angular.js:14516 `

Comment: `Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost:3000/lvl/2/data","headers":{"Authorization":"Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"data":{"Code":"test data"}},"statusText":""}`

Comment: and I dont know about OPTIONS in my nodejs code @JaromandaX

Comment: see this `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check` - that's the OPTIONS preflight that is failing - read about CORS preflight to understand - if you were using express on the server, you'd use express-cors - https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-cors

Answer (score 0):

You can temporary disable checking CORS with extension for browser:

**Chrome:**

[Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related)

For **Opera** you should install:

1)[Extension allows you to install extensions from Chrome Web Store](https://addons.opera.com/pl/extensions/details/download-chrome-extension-9/?display=en)

2)[Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related)